# Route to a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing query output to a CSV file in a folder called 'reports_output' inside my 'report_runs' views folder. The file names need to be generated based upon the name given by users running reports and other parameters like current time etc. I have two issues:

1. How to generate unique file names using Time.now converted to string of numbers (like version numbers in db/migrate) ? and
2. How to do correct routing to all these .csv files?

I was able to write files with simple names e.g. Item_List.csv below, but not been able to view the files by clicking on the url to the file in my show view in browser. The error says :

```
No route matches "/report_runs/report_outputs/Item_List.csv"
```

Comment: Your problem is two-fold. Let's break it and solve each part individually.

Comment: For the 1st part, let's assume you have a .csv file under the folder you specified. What did you write in routes.rb file for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You can generate a filename that includes the current time using simple string interpolation and you can format the string with [Time#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
file_name = "item_list#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.csv"
```

2: If you want to serve static assets like your .csv files then you can write them to the public folder. So for example if you create a file in `public/report_runs/report_outputs/Item_List.csv` it will be accessible from the path given in your example.

Comment: For 2 I tried writing to public/report_outputs/ directory. When I browse to the file I am facing the same error.: http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/report_outputs/Item_List_4.csv    Routing Error

No route matches "/public/report_outputs/Item_List_4.csv"

Comment: try 127.0.0.1:3000/report_outputs/Item_List_4.csv

Comment: Ok this works when I directly browse to the file in browser. So now I just need to create correct link in my show. My current show has  <b>File path:</b>
  <%= link_to "View Report", "#{@report_run.file_path}"%> This creates the url:http://127.0.0.1:3000/report_runs/public/report_outputs/Item_List_4_20120820122124.csv . How do I remove the "/report_runs/public" from in in my link?

Comment: I'm not sure what @report_run is so I can't tell you what the best approach is, maybe try some simple string manipulation? `@report_run.file_path.gsub('report_runs/public/', '')` would work. Just search Ruby String for the full API reference.

Comment: I made it to work using this:   <%= link_to "View Report", "#{@report_run.file_path.sub('public','')}"%>
Thanks much for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the CSV on the fly in the controller, then you can route to it like this:

```
<%= link_to item_list_path(:format => "csv") %>
```

Assuming that your controller is `ItemList`.